# What to do with deprecated encrypt_input and decrypt_input in Profile:Edit

Tags: safecracker, profile-edit

Working on a site where we're using Profile:Edit to register users using the {exp:profile:register}. In this particular case, we're using the parameter 'group_id' to register a user into a particular member group, which can be done by an admin on the front end through a restricted access dashboard.

Running into an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Channel_form_lib::encrypt_input() in 
/path/to/system/third_party/profile/mod.profile.php on line 880
```

A quick bit of research tells me that that method was deprecated as of EE v2.6, and we have just upgraded to EE v2.8.1/2.9 (and soon to v2.9). This also goes hand-in-hand with the Channel_form_lib::decrypt_input() method that is also being user in mod.profile.php

Can any EE developer/programmers point me in the right direction of a simple change to the method I can move to?

Answer (score 0):

I scheduled a support call with Mighty Big Robot for this morning, and before I started it had an email with an updated version of Profile:Edit in my mailbox to test.

Basically this included updates to cater for the deprecated functions as well as a minor hack I had made to a local version so that I could use the {exp:profile:view} tag on the same template as {exp:channel:form}.

The current version is now v1.2.0 and suspect it will be made available through the MBR website soon for those that might be experiencing the same problems.

Should note that I did need to hit the Module settings page for Profile:Edit and re-submit the settings for it to work 100%.

(Many thanks to Chris Barrett for working with us at such short notice)

Comment: A heads up that 1.2.1 is now current http://mightybigrobot.com/docs/profile-edit/ - can download via http://mightybigrobot.com/cart/account once logged in.